# OpenVPN: Single-Device Connection Failure (code=10060)

Tags: openvpn

I have a single Windows 10 box that will not connect to my Linux OpenVPN server. I verified that its certificate is valid (and re-issued it). The log (on the client) has the following over and over:

> Tue Jan 30 10:01:40 2018 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]:443
>
> Tue Jan 30 10:01:40 2018 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
>
> Tue Jan 30 10:01:40 2018 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]:443 [nonblock]
>
> Tue Jan 30 10:01:41 2018 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]:443
>
> Tue Jan 30 10:01:41 2018 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
>
> Tue Jan 30 10:01:41 2018 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]:443
>
> Tue Jan 30 10:01:59 2018 read TCP_CLIENT: Connection timed out (WSAETIMEDOUT) (code=10060)
>
> Tue Jan 30 10:01:59 2018 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
>
> Tue Jan 30 10:01:59 2018 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
>
> Tue Jan 30 10:01:59 2018 Restart pause, 300 second(s)

While the cert was revoked, I saw the same log content generated, no new errors.

I verified that I can telnet from Windows to the server on port 443. I also verified that tracert from the Windows box, doesn't show any unexpected drops.

If I grep for the server, in openvpn-status.log (on the server), there are no entries (but I can see other connections when I browse the file).

Finally, I'm told that there is no web-filtering appliance on the Windows client's network.

What else can I check? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the customer had a content filter, of which we were unaware.